# Has stackplot been removed from the matplotlib library?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Just been reading about .stackplot after trying to replicate this chart type using Pandas, IPython and Seaborn.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot

I've read about the original pull requests from a couple of years ago, but my recently-installed versions don't have that method available.

Does anyone know if it was removed, or are you successfully using it?

Comment: Works for me in matplotlib 1.3.1

Comment: Thanks @askewchan - I'll take a second run in that case, it must be user error.

Comment: You're welcome @phil.  If you find the answer, please either post it here or delete the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, it hasn't been removed. It's definitely there in the latest build, and looks to be compatible with Seaborn aesthetics as well.

My issues were linked to problems with my overall environment on OSX Mavericks. pip install --upgrade hadn't upgraded matplotlib when I thought I was running off the latest version.